# need to consume DataTable getting from a web api and show it at the client side in an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I need to consume the datatable originating from web api and show the data in a tabular format or gridview in the client side in an aspx page of another project.Any help is appriciated.

Web api controller code-

```
public class ClientDetailController : ApiController
    {

        public DataTable getDetail(string id)
        {

            DataAccessLayer dal = new DataAccessLayer();
            DataTable dt= dal.GetClientDetails(id);
            return dt;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you see when you call this API directly from browser? You need to check about calling API using JQuery Ajax.

Comment: Its returning the data in JSON.

Comment: Use **Jquery DataTable**. Please check [my this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44970893/2376652) Let me know if you are unable to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
        var uri = 'http://localhost:62983/api/clientdetail/getdetail';
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var id = $('#HFClientId').val();
            $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id)
            .done(function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                    $('#student').append("<tr><td>" + item.Cl_stateid + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.SM_Name + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.CL_CityID + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.LM_Name + '%' + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.CL_BranchName + "</td></tr>");
                });
            });
        });
```